# Default screen orientation on android devices

Tags: android, screen-orientation, touchscreen

i've seen alot of questions here about screen orientation but mine is kind of different. 
 
I'm trying to find a way of figuring out at run-time what is the default orientation of the touch-screen. 
i.e: for tablets it's landscape, for phones it's portrait etc. 
I need this info because i'm dealing directly with the touchscreen hardware, and it's x,y grid is constant, and not based on the current system orientation.
any ideas?
Edit: I'll refine my question:
 How can i tell if the physical tounch screen, is oriented like system orientation portrait or landscape.

Edit (Answer): OK, so: `getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()`

 will give you the current rotation degree from the default touch screen axis. 
 
e.g:
 On tablets, where the the touch screen axis are aligned with the landscape orientation, the obove will return 0 on landscape.
On phones where the touch screen axis are aligned with the portrait orientation, the obove will return 0 on portrait. yay! :)

Comment: A short short answer is enumerate your all your targeted dimens and see which one gets loaded.

Comment: @FrankSposro this is sad. i don't accept answers when they don't answer my question. if you want to answer, answer. if don't, i don't need your five pounds..

Answer (score 1):

There is no default.  Don't write your code assuming that portrait is the default. If your app is orientation-sensitive, put your layout files in layout-port and layout-land, not in layout.  layout is only for those activities and dialogs which are not orientation-specific.

Comment: "There is no default", you are absolutely wrong. the physical touch screen is oriented according to a certain direction. landscape or portrait. and it doesn't change together with the system screen orientation. i don't understand why people who don't have an answer to a question, answer it anyways.. i don't need two diffrent layouts, that doesn't have anything to do with my question.

Comment: Ahhh, you're right.  I did misunderstand.  I think if you're working at the hardware level, and not through the Android API, you'll have to get in touch with the manufacturer of the device.

Comment: Actually there is an api-level solution. From Display.getRotation() documentation: Returns the rotation of the screen from its "natural" orientation. :) hope you can use it one day